# Rendering a file with swig templates without using express

Tags: node.js, swig-template

I use swig (django style templating engine) with express successfully all the time. I'm trying to use swig outside of request/render and simply pass context to a swig marked up file and have it generate the HTML.

I can't figure out the API without using express.

From the website they have this example that I can't get to work:
https://github.com/paularmstrong/swig/tree/bd3f5a0dc08078ffd4372fa61248f8d50d8cbbf8

```
var template  = require('swig'); // v1.1.0
var tmpl = template.compileFile('/path/to/template.html');
tmpl.render({
    pagename: 'awesome people',
    authors: ['Paul', 'Jim', 'Jane']
});
```

There is an error saying `render` doesn't exist on the tmpl object?
(The compileFile seems to be working fine.)

There is clearly something I'm not understanding or that I need to include outside of the example.

**update:** Added in version number of swig after comments to make it clear what version I'm working with.

Comment: Are you using the deprecated v0.14.0 or v1.0.0? The link you gave is for v0.14.0, but your comment on Kim T's answer makes it look like you are not.

Comment: Hi. That's the issue. New version used with old documentation. Yes, I'm on the latest version of swig v1.1.0. It works - easy as apple pie - after referencing your current documentation here: http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/

Comment: @PaulArmstrong Not sure how wrap up questions answered in comments. Can you answer it officially and I'll be able to accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From comments on original question:

It looks like you're trying to use Swig@~1.0, yet the link you gave points to Swig@0.14.0. The API for Swig changed dramatically between v0 and v1.

Documentation for the current supported version can always be found at http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at https://github.com/assemble/assemble? Assemble is a static site generator based on Grunt, it's really easy to use, and Swig is one of the engines for Assemble. Here are some resources:

- https://github.com/assemble/assemble-swig
- https://github.com/assemble/boilerplate-swig
- https://github.com/assemble/swig-extensions

Comment: Thanks for highlighting this project. :!

Answer (score 2):

Here is some steps to render swig template . 1. install swig using command `npm install swig --save`

-create server.js

```
var http = require('http'), swig=require('swig');
http.createServer(function(request, response){
var tpl = swig.compileFile('index.html');
renderedHtml =  tpl({
                         say:'hello word'
                    });
response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
response.end(renderedHtml);
}).listen(8080);
```

-create index.html template file as.

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
   </head>
    <body>
     <h2>{{say}}</h2>   
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Pleaseeeeeee don't shoutttttt!

Comment: sorry i am being late. due to some personal problem. thanks @ Paresh Mayani .

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to tell swig the path to the templates?

```
var swig  = require('swig');
swig.init({ root: __dirname + '/templates' });

var tmpl = swig.compileFile('home.html');
tmpl.render({
    pagename: 'awesome people',
    authors: ['Paul', 'Jim', 'Jane']
});
```

Comment: Hi Kim. Thanks for the answer. With `swig.init` I get `TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'init'`. However, I was passing the full path directly into the compileFile('full/path/home.html'); And that worked because it gave back the compiled html inside an array.I think the issue is something else.